# Will creating a time series solve issues related to repeated cross-sectional analysis?

Tags: regression, cross-section

I aim to explore agricultural productivity over time using repeated cross-sections. If I assume a functional form and estimate TFP for each farm in the sample how would I examine the drivers of TFP over time?

Would it work to look at the average partial effects of farm characteristics on TFP for each year and assess this as a time series or would it be possible to pseudo panel the TFP estimates over time using farm characteristics then run regressions of TFP against the farm characteristics for each year then assess these partial effects over time?

Also, how do I tell the difference between pooled cross sections and repeated cross sections?